# Duplicating rows n times, where n is a value of a string

Tags: r, repeat

I have a dataset where I list states with their respective cities, some of these places have been aggregated (not by me) and are classified as `"Other ([count of places])" (e.g. Other (99))`. Appended to this list of places are numeric `'count'` values. I'd like to 1.) find the average count per place and 2.) duplicate these 'Other...' places along with the average according to the number within the parenthesis. Example below:

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(state = c('A','B'), city = c('Other (3)','Other (2)'), count = c('250','50'))
```

Output:

| state | city | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Other (3) | 83.333 |
| A | Other (3) | 83.333 |
| A | Other (3) | 83.333 |
| B | Other (2) | 25.000 |
| B | Other (2) | 25.000 |

So far I've only been able to figure out how to pull the numbers from the parenthesis and create an average:

```
average = df$count/as.numeric(gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", df$city))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend your example with the followign code:

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(state = c('A','B'), city = c('Other (3)','Other (2)'), count = c('250','50'))
times <- as.numeric(gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", df$city))
df$count <- as.numeric(df$count)/times
output <- df[rep(seq_along(times),times),]
```

The key addition is the line creating output, which uses row indexing on the input dataframe to repeat each row as required.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `uncount`.  Extract the numeric part in 'city' with `parse_number`, divide the 'count' by 'n' and replicate the rows with `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(n = readr::parse_number(city), count = as.numeric(count)/n) %>%
    uncount(n)
```

-output

```
state      city    count
1     A Other (3) 83.33333
2     A Other (3) 83.33333
3     A Other (3) 83.33333
4     B Other (2) 25.00000
5     B Other (2) 25.00000
```